# Opening a form in a project from other exe (reference exe) throws an object reference error C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say - I am Developing Project A and already have an project B's output as an exe file.
I am using B's output (Say - B.exe) as a reference in A project.

I need to use B.exe's forms directly in A.

Example:

```
Namespace A
{
    B.Reports.TaxReport reportForm = new B.Reports.TaxReport();
    reportForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The problem here is, the form loads correctly inside the new Exe with all the database fetching. But if the user does any Operation such as Add / Update / Data fetch, the current exe throws an exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an Object'.

How can this problem be tackled? If no, is there any workaround that can help me in opening the forms from a reference EXE into the current under development project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the `.exe` as a project reference. Best way is to go change the project B's output to dll(*Currently it's exe*). to change it go to `Project B's` property and change the `Output Type` as `Class Library`. Then rebuild `B` and add the project B's output dll as reference to Project A and call the Form in dll B. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

> But if the user does any Operation such as Add / Update / Data fetch, the current exe throws an exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an Object'.

Then the form probably has some properties it expects to be set, or a constructor overload it expects you to call.

Comment: That was my first thought, but unfortunately the form does not need any properties or the constructor overloads.

Comment: If you say that with such confidence, you must have the source of the form. Open the form file in your project, put a breakpoint and see what happens.

Comment: Both are my own projects. But the reference EXE does not allow me to take a peek into the code as it is referred to as 'MetaData'.

Comment: It does if you just open the source file from Visual Studio.

Comment: Will give it a try and get back here. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeMaster - The suggestion worked. Thanks a lot. It also can be dealt in a better way by using DLL instead of an EXE.

Comment: @AccessDenied - Your comment was not visible maybe it you removed it. But, still, Thanks a ton. The Dll part helped and did the trick.

Comment: @Sarang just undeleted. Mark it as answer if it helped to solve the issue. it will help other community memebers to solve the similar issue. thanks